# Advice on choosing Standard or Durable Reduced Availability for file storage Google cloud storage package

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a web app that is based around uploading and downloading files, and I'm not sure what the best choice is for me. I need files to be available for download on demand with minimal delay. There's a latency listed for the Standard and Nearline packages, but nothing other than "reduced availability" for the other option. WTF does that actually mean?

Are we talking 500ms, 5s, a week? Do they mail me diskettes? The documentation for the Google cloud products suite is shoddy to say the least.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need files to be available for download on demand with minimal delay.

Minimal delay is not the important part. Both Standard and Reduced Availability will serve your objects quickly. "Available on demand" is the key phrase. Standard objects provide a monthly uptime SLO of 99.9%, while DRA objects provide an availability SLO of 99%.

0.9% is a small number, but that's potentially 6 and a half hours per month. Are you comfortable with your objects being unavailable for up to 6.5 hours per month? If so, DRA is a good choice for you. If not, use standard.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I would either use Standard or Reduced Availability type buckets. The only difference between them is the availability of your data but same performance and latency.

You can review some real life benchmarks to get impression on how Google Cloud Storage performs

http://blog.zachbjornson.com/2015/12/29/cloud-storage-performance.html